# Angular 12 Socket IO failed to compile

Tags: angular, typescript, sockets, websocket

Hi I created service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BattleshipService {

  uri = 'ws://ntp.task.gda.pl:13'

  socket: any;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.uri); // <-- failed to compile
   }

}
```

I installed socket.io-client and @types/socket.io-client.

When I try to compile this Im getting stacktrace like that:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-parser/lib/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\admin\IdeaProjects\Remote-Battleship-Game\Battleship-game\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-parser\lib\index.js'
```

Do you know what did I wrong or what is missing? Thanks for your answers.